# Advice migrating jboss AS5 project to AS7

Tags: java, ant, maven, jboss

We have a large project ear that contains a `.har` and a `.war`, currently built with ant - running on JBoss AS 5. We would like to migrate this application to JBoss AS 7.  Much of the AS 7 documentation is Maven-centric. The project does not currently conform to the Maven directory structure conventions and would have to be completely restructured.

Is it worth migrating this application to Maven?
Or would it be quicker to just leave it using ant?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on complexity of the build process.

I would recommend to convert to Maven. AFAIK it's going to be the main build tool for whole JBoss, and many efforts of JBoss as whole are, and will be, Maven centric.

Comment: My sense is that it is moderately complex build process - the end result is a *har file and a *war file inside of the *ear file.  I have a couple of questions at this point: 1. I tried building with ant inside of AS7 just to see what would happen, and of course I ran into class loading problems.  Our build.xml set up a classpath where the build process can look up dependencies ( <path id="build.classpath">   <pathelement location="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/activemq-core-5.5.0.jar"/>) - I know AS7 has been moved to modularized class loading - but does it not honor these ant directives?

Comment: My other question is - to get around the class loading problems I created a *ear/meta-inf/MANIFEST.MF file that contains 'Class-Path: /path/to/my/libdirectory/activemq-core-5.5.0.jar') - but I'm still getting the same package does not exist errors on build.  Not sure how I can fix this, I feel like I'm already following the migration to as7 documentation on the jboss site.

Comment: Probably this two links will be helpful: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7 and https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Home

Comment: Please ask additional questions as separate questions, perhaps link them from here.

Comment: And just not to look like I insist on that - I am not sure about the ant thing. What do you mean by building _inside_ AS? Generally, I guess the normal way of packaging libs to Java EE archive should work. Try asking at JBoss forums, too.